# diesel_cli setup returns error regarding DATABASE_URL

Tags: mysql, rust, database-connection, rust-diesel

I am trying to setup `Diesel-CLI` but it always returns some error regarding **DATABASE_URL**.

For this question, Let's assume:

- user=root
- password=#Abcd1234
- host=localhost
- database=codeforces
- mysql server socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock/

```
For DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:#Abcd1234@localhost/codeforces  
and DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:#Abcd1234@localhost/codeforces.sql?socket=(/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock)
```

> Error: Unknown MySQL server host 'root' (-2)

```
For DATABASE_URL=mysql://root@localhost/codeforces  
and DATABASE_URL=mysql://root@localhost/codeforces?socket=(/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock)
```

> Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

```
For DATABASE_URL=mysql://root@127.0.0.1/codeforces
```

> Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

```
For DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:#Abcd1234@127.0.0.1/codeforces
```

> Error: Unknown MySQL server host 'root' (-2)

I have tried googling it but no results so far. I don't know where i am making the mistake.

So my question is:
How to reslove this error?

Comment: `#` is a special character in URLs, so I don't think you can have it in the password like that. Anything after it would effectively be ignored..

Comment: yeah now it worked when i changed the password to something else. Thanks @Frxstrem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My DATABASE_URL was not working because i was using reserved characters in the url.

From [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) specification:

> Only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL.

For those who are getting this error on changing 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' :

> Error: Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: /usr//usr/lib64/mysql/plugin//caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Try doing this(It worked for me):

> mysql>ALTER USER 'yourusername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yourpassword';